# CH/J sound and the position of the tip of the tongue

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

Question about American English:

According to these YouTube videos ([Example 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unfuGPc3iXo), [Example 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJdx5kTmktk), [Example 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRdSQRMWb4Y)), to make the **CH-/J-** sound, we place the tip of the tongue on the alveolar ridge behind the top teeth similar to the **T-/D-** position.

But for me, when I say the following phrases or words, that's not the position of the tip of the tongue. The tip of the tongue ends up somewhere near the **bottom teeth**. It's hard to flick back the tip of the tongue to the top/roof of the mouth to the **T-/D-** position in these quick connections:

- with the **ch**ild
- to the **g**ym
- for the **j**ob
- ques**t**ion
- Eu**g**ene

For me, what happens is, the back of the tongue is raised and pressed against the back teeth, but the front portion of the tongue points to the **bottom front** teeth. I still make the puff/plosive sound for the CH-/J- and it's still possible even when the tip of the tongue is next to the bottom front teeth. But if I were to follow these official instructions, it would be hard to flick the tip back to the roof of the mouth after vowels like "eh" or "oo."

Am I doing it wrong? Any comments? Thanks

UPDATE: I quote from multiple professional English resources:

https://pronuncian.com/podcasts/episode24

> Both of these sounds begin with the tongue in the **same position as the**
> **t sound and d sound**, with the tip of the tongue right behind the upper
> front teeth

https://1specialplace.com/2021/09/25/articulation-therapy-teaching-ch-and-j-sounds/

> the /ch/ and /j/ sounds are produced with a complete obstruction
> formed by the **tongue tip touching the area called the alveolar ridge**,
> which is right behind the upper front teeth.

These aren't random people, these are professional English tutors. Is it even possible to hit that top alveolar spot in quick pronunciation of `with the child`, `to the gym`, `for the job`, etc., where the tongue is far away from it? You'd have to do a lot of weird flicking to the top to hit that alveolar spot.

Comment: For that sound, I do not place the tip of the tongue anywhere: it floats. The sound is made by the middle of the tongue against the palate.

Comment: ... particularly the last example 'Eugene' where there is no preceding tongue action to confuse. As opposed to the first three examples where the tip of the tongue has moved from behind the top teeth after saying 'the'.

Comment: Weather Vane, that's exactly what I do! The tip of the tongue "floats," and not particularly anywhere; and only the middle part is against the palate. You've just described 100% what I do. So how come all these 3 videos say a very different thing, that this sound involves the tip placed on the alveolar ridge as for T-/D-? All are all 3 of them wrong?

Comment: That is not what you say in the question.

Comment: Certainly Wikipedia says [voiceless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_postalveolar_affricate) and [voiced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_postalveolar_affricate) affricates in English and other languages are typically done with the [blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue#Structure) of the tongue. Moral is to consult an authoritative source (or at least Wikipedia) and not rely exclusively on random people on YouTube.

Comment: The tip isn't really involved as much as the blade. You should be able to feel where the majority of the noise is coming from.

Comment: Well, the blade is still close to the tip, in the front. Are you saying that the front is involved in making CH/J? For me (and apparently Weather Vane), the *back/center of the tongue* is used in making this sound, while the front is not really used at all. The back/center is pressed against the upper palate.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am making that sound with the part of the tongue only a cm or so back from the tip. If I make the German ch sound, I use the back part of the tongue (maybe 2 cm back from the center of the tongue).

Comment: In Mandarin Chinese there are fricative sounds (zh vs j, ch  vs q, sh vs x in pinyin) distinguished by how far forward the tongue is moved. They are fairly difficult for native English speakers to distinguish (luckily they combine with different vowels, so the distinction is never critical to distinguishing a word)

Comment: Sorry, those are affricates, not fricatives.

Comment: I haven't watched those videos, but that's how I would _teach_ someone to produce this sound. Perhaps that's what's up here?

Comment: My question is, how would you be able to quickly bring the tongue tip back to the alveolar ridge in a word like "CHARGE" or "CHARGING STATION"? You start out with the initial CH on the alveolar ridge, but then the R is a rear sound that takes your tongue all the way back, and then you have to quickly flick back to the alveolar ridge for the G. It's much easier (and almost identical) if you simply touch the palate with the middle of your tongue, and words like CHARGE become more natural and with better pronunciation of the R.